# Is this the correct way to style a HTML document using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of coding as well as CSS and have put together a sample page however am unsure if I am doing it correctly i.e. is the use of my CSS valid? I seem to be getting the required layout however would like to know if I am making any mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content= "" />

    <title>Example</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />

    <style type="text/css">

    body {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }

    #wrapper {


    }

    #header {

        background-image: url('images/bg-inner-page.gif');
        height: 200px;

    }

    #logo {

        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        left: 100px;

    }

    #topnav {

        position: relative;
        top: 35px;
        left: 300px;

    }

    #content {

        background-color: orange;

    }

    #footer {

        background-color: blue;

    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                logo
            </div>

            <div id="topnav">
                nav
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">content</div>
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a mistake? You said it is working? Are you wondering if this is a best practice? That really is a different question than what you are asking.

Comment: @spinon - what I mean by mistake is that, am I using CSS correctly i.e. the right use of padding, margins, inheritance, etc. I said it is working because it gives me the layout I want however I don't know whether my coding is efficient and I am using the tags, properties, selectors, etc correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS seems fine, there are no problems, but I do offer 2 suggestions:

1) Move your CSS into a separate file. This allows browsers to cache it and reduces your (and their) bandwidth usage. It also keeps your HTML file smaller, which makes it easier to read.

2) Although ID selectors are perfectly OK, I tend to favour class selectors (e.g. `.class-selector { ... }`) instead of ID selectors (e.g. `#id-selector { ... }`) since you might need a second wrapper div later in your code, and your ID's have to be unique. Using the class attribute will allow you to have two (or more) wrappers with the same style in your code (which is part of the beauty of CSS). More than once I've seen people create stylesheets that repeat themselves over and over again because they use only ID selectors to style content, which defeats the point of CSS.

Comment: I'd rephrase `(2)`. The `id` selectors are fine in this case. You only use classes when you have many elements which should look alike, like images with captions.

Comment: @Blender - Yeah it was poorly worded, hopefully it should read better now.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/). Just copy & paste your code into the form and it will tell you what's wrong.

For me, it just pointed to that `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=UTF-8" />
```

You forgot the opening quote before `UTF-8`.

But your CSS is completely fine. As long as it's valid and works across all the browsers, don't worry about it.

Comment: I like HTML Validator, the Firefox add-on. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/

Comment: They're both the same thing, but the add-on is pretty nice to have, as it saves you a few clicks.

Comment: I used it extensively when I was learning HTML. Very handy, since it shows results on every page, without having to specifically go to the online validator.

Comment: Actually, the correct HTML is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`, not `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />`.

Comment: @mc10 - I think you're right.

Comment: @Blender - Thanks. That was actually a typo in the code. That should have read `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />. 
`

Comment: @mc10 - That's right. Just saw it when Blender pointed it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Blender - The reason I am 'worried' about my CSS is because I don't know if it is efficient and if I am using is correctly. I don't want it simply working if the code is inefficient.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - I think it should be `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`; note the semicolon after `html`.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - You are absolutely correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Do you know of any cross-platform extensions or add-ons I could use?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Cross-platform? What do mean? Extensions/add-ons are usually specific to a browser, although there are some with versions for each browser for some (Firebug, for instance - Get it). I also like Firecookie and Web Developer (although Web Developer may be included with FF as of FF4). I am primarily a FF developer, due to my comfort with the toolkits.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - Troll through here, just to see what's out there. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/web-development/

Comment: @Jared Farrish- What I meant by cross-platform is a tool that I can use with FireFox, Google Chrome, etc. I just installed Firebug although am unsure how it works yet.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - I'm not sure, since I am almost entirely a FF developer (I then test in IE mostly). Firebug, you should read up on `console.log`, which is what you will use most (which is JS). But overall, it's a great tool for a number of different reasons. Watch some videos: http://www.google.com/search?q=firebug+tutorial&tbm=vid

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are getting the desired output in the various browsers then that is fine. However, you may want to place your CSS code in an external file and link to it. This way the same styles can be applied to mutliple pages. I see that you have a link tag with no href attribute value so its just a matter of providing the name of the css file.

Comment: Thanks. The concern I have with my code is whether it is efficient. Don't want code that just works. Would like to have code that works, is efficient and adheres to standards.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine except for this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=UTF-8" />
```

**UPDATE:** You forget to put simicolon after html and before charset like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

It is a good practice to separate your CSS code from HTML to reduce the page size, save bandwidth.
There are some lines you can avoid it like:

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta name="author" content= "" />

 <base href="" />
```

Avoid this line if you don't have any external CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
```

Comment: @SIFE - See the comments on Blender's answer.

Comment: @Jared I read it, are you trying to say something?

Comment: @SIFE - Your first tip about the double-quote is probably wrong. There should be a semicolon after `text/html`, not another double quote.

Comment: @SIFE - Why would I want avoid the meta and base tags? The reason I had the code of the external CSS is because I intend to move my internal stylesheet to an external one as soon as I have it working.

Comment: @Jared I forget it, thx for the note. @PeanutsMonkey If you are not going to use avoid it. I thought you are going to make this page as a template, for that I said you will not need `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: @SIFE - Thanks. I generally have all the code there so that I have a template to work with but point taken about not having code in the document if I am not using it.

Comment: @SIFE - Your edit isn't exactly right - you put a colon in instead of a semicolon, and are missing a space (not sure if the latter is required).